# get DataTable Column values into array

Tags: arrays, datatable

I need help capturing DataTable column values into an array.
I was able to get the DataTable column names, but not able to capture the columns values.

Here is my code:

```
    protected Array getDtColNames(DataTable myDt) // this works 
    {
        // capture gv column header 
        int intColCount = myDt.Columns.Count;
        string[] colNames = new string[intColCount];
        for (int i = 0; i <= myDt.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            colNames[i] = myDt.Columns[i].ToString();
        }
        return colNames;
    }

    protected Array getDtColValues(DataTable myDt)
    {
        // capture gv column header 
        int intColCount = myDt.Columns.Count;
        string[] colValues = new string[intColCount];
        for (int i = 0; i <= myDt.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            colValues[i] = ???? // not able to capture values 
        }
        return colValues;
    }
```

Thanks for your support